# Equality Constrained Optimization - Conditions to guarantee compactness

Tags: optimization, compactness

Consider a general maximization problem: $X$ and $Y$ compact sets, $f,g: X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$, $f,g$ continuous. Problem is $\max_{\substack{x \in X, y\in Y \\ \text{s.t. } g(x,y)=0}}f(x,y)$. To be able use Weierstrass theorem, I am trying to ensure that $\left\{(x,y) \in X \times Y : g(x,y)=0\right\}$ is a compact set (which amounts to saying $g^{-1}(\left\{0\right\})$ is compact) but since pre-images of compact sets under continuous functions are not always compact, I can't ensure this. Is there a minimal set of assumptions I can add to achieve what I want?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Since $g$ is continuous, $g^{-1}(\{0\})$ is a closed subset of $X \times Y$.

Comment: Oh so it is already compact. Duh. Thanks :)